# Не хватает пробела в заголовке письма о восстановлении пароля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Если попытаться восстановить пароль (по [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) адресу), то на почту придёт письмо с заголовком

> Восстановление учётной записи **—Stack** Overflow на русском

> [image: скриншот заголовка письма]

Добавьте, пожалуйста, пробел после длинного тире. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавили. Будет на сайте после подкачки transifex и пересборки движка.